# What is the correct name for a stacked bar chart with a single bar (series), and many stacked segments?

Tags: visualization, terminology

I had a treemap that was better expressed in a linear format.

This resulted in a chart that I don't know the name of. It's something like a stacked bar chart, with just a single column/row:

[image: Chart example, stacked single bar]
*(This example is a simplified version with less groupings)*

It's similar to a bar chart, a treemap, a marimekko chart, etc., and some names come to mind based on these other charts, like:

- Linear treemap
- Stacked single bar chart
- Linear segment chart

It's not a complicated chart, so I thought it would already have a succinct name. But I'm having trouble finding any kind of shorthand terminology for this chart format.